# How to add a script reference in view page (index.cshtml) dynamically?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to add the script reference in MVC application view page dynamically based on some condition. For example, need to add the script (jquery) reference
    
in my index.cshtml page at first line.

Comment: Create a script  section in _Layout page and define condition in in this section on view page.

Comment: My exact scenario is need to add the script reference in the view page pro grammatically. For example, if i run the exe file need to add the references in the view pages present in targeted folder.